# netbeans editor formatter's source code

Tags: netbeans, formatting, editor

In netbeans code editor ALT+SHIFT+F key combination formats source code.

I am curious how this formatter works.

Where can I find formatter's source code in netbeans source code repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on netbeans forum, and got answer there. Maybe it will be interesting for somebody.

> org.netbeans.modules.java.source.save.Reformatter

Here is a 
[link](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic61037.html)